# How can you get the Google+ Profile of the current user when using Google Cloud Endpoint's (Java) built in authentication?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus, google-cloud-endpoints

## My Setup

**Backend:** Google App Engine (Java) w/ Google Cloud Endpoints *using Endpoint's built in authentication*

**Frontend:** AngularJS web app

## Problem

I need to get the Google+ profile for my users. The keyword "me" can generally be used to get the current user's Google+ profile, however since all the authentication, in Google Cloud Endpoints, is done under the hood, I don't see anyway to get credentials, nor a token, for the current user. All you get it the `com.google.appengine.api.users.User` object.

**Is there any way to get user credentials, or the access token, when using Google Cloud Endpoint's built in authentication?**

*Note: Google+ profile ID is different form Google account ID.*

### Possible Solution

I could just use the Google+ JS client with the keyword "me" and have the user send their Google+ ID and then subsequently store it and tie it to their Google Account ID, but this would be incredible insecure as the user could hack their way to sending the ID of any Google+ account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get the user access token when using Google Cloud Endpoint's built in authentication.

1. Add the parameter `HttpServletRequest request` to your Google Cloud endpoint as shown below. This will allow you to get the raw request.
2. You will then need to retreive the header called *Authentication*. This will get a Bearer access token that will allow you to build credentials to impersonate the authenticated user.
3. Next you will use that Bearer access token to build a `com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential` object. You will need this to build the Plus service.
4. Use the Plus builder to build a Plus service object with the credential you just created.

### Sample Code

```
@ApiMethod(path = "myPath")
public void myEndpoint(HttpServletRequest request, ParmOne paramOne, ...) throws OAuthRequestException {

    if (user == null) {
        throw new OAuthRequestException("Authentication error!");
    }

    GoogleCredential credentialAsUser = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(request.getHeader("Authorization").substring(7)); // Start string at index position 7 to remove prefix "Bearer" from token.

    Plus plus = new Plus.Builder(new UrlFetchTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credentialAsUser).setApplicationName("my-app").build();
    Person profile = plus.people().get("me").execute();

}
```

### Documentation

The Java docs for the Google Plus client can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/plus/v1/java/latest/index.html?overview-tree.html).

The Java docs for instructions on creating Google credentials can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential).

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! That is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Jokus Did you ever try this with an Android Endpoints client? Does not work for me.

Comment: I only got it working for a few hours, now it crashes again :( What I figured out is calling the api from the api-manager is generating an access_token in the request header. That works with the code above. If I call the api from my android app, the header will contain an id_token that will not work with the code above. That should be the problem ... Any ideas how to change that auth-type? The credentials are generated this way in android: `GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,"server:client_id:" + Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID);`

Comment: @Jokus I don't know if you can. Let me know if you figure something out. I might just say the heck with it and get the Profile from the Android side.

Comment: @Jokus I suspect that it would work if you could get Google Sign-In to work with Google Cloud Endpoints, but sadly I could not get that to work either.

Comment: I finaly got it working! As I already said `GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience` sends an id_token (very long) in the request-header. To get an access_token simply use `credentials = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN));` in your app and send it to your api (for example: `new yourApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),new JacksonFactory(), credentials);`) That way the code above should work with android apps ;)

Comment: @Jokus Dude, you the boss! Make a separate answer, and I'll up vote it. That's definitely worthy of a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Additional Answer for Android Clients

#### Problem

In addition to the Marc's answer it is important that the `GoogleCredentials`-Object needs an `access_token` in the request-header.

If you call the endpoint with your apiExplorer or a [javascript endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js), this token is already served in the Authorization-header. But if you follow the docs for an [android client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android) your requests header contains an `id_token`, so `GoogleCredentials.setAccessToken` does not work.

#### Solution

To change the type of authorization to an `access_token` simply create your `GoogleAccountCredential`-Object in Android with `usingOAuth2` instead of `usingAudience`.

#### Example

Replace this code in your Android App

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,
"server:client_id:1-web-app.apps.googleusercontent.com");
```

with this

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, 
Collections.singleton(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN));
```

and send it to your Api, as it is explained by the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android)

```
Helloworld.Builder helloWorld = new Helloworld.Builder(AppConstants.HTTP_TRANSPORT,
  AppConstants.JSON_FACTORY,credential);
```